# Angular 5 with Express, sessions not working

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular5

I'm new to Angular 2/4/5 (migrating from AngularJS). 
I'm running a NodeJs + Express server at:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

I'm running my Angular project as:

```
ng serve --open
```

which runs as:

```
http://localhost:4200
```

I created HttpService with following function to make http requests:

```
sendRequest(requestObject): Promise<any> {
    // set created_at / updated_at on request if create or update operation
    if (this.isDataUpdateOperation(requestObject)) {
        requestObject = this.setDate(requestObject);
    }

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'withCredentials': true });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    if(requestObject.REQUEST_METHOD == this.constants.REQUEST_METHODS.GET){
        return this.http.post(
            this.constants.SERVER.ROOT + this.constants.SERVER.API_PATH + requestObject.API_URL,
            requestObject.REQUEST_DATA,
            options).toPromise()
            .then((response)=>{
                return response.json();
            });
    }
    else if(requestObject.REQUEST_METHOD == this.constants.REQUEST_METHODS.POST){
        return this.http.post(
            this.constants.SERVER.ROOT + this.constants.SERVER.API_PATH + requestObject.API_URL,
            requestObject.REQUEST_DATA,
            options).toPromise()
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            });
    }
    else if(requestObject.REQUEST_METHOD == this.constants.REQUEST_METHODS.PUT){
        return this.http.put(
            this.constants.SERVER.ROOT + this.constants.SERVER.API_PATH + requestObject.API_URL,
            requestObject.REQUEST_DATA,
            options).toPromise()
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            });
    }
    else if(requestObject.REQUEST_METHOD == this.constants.REQUEST_METHODS.DELETE){
        return this.http.delete(
            this.constants.SERVER.ROOT + this.constants.SERVER.API_PATH + requestObject.API_URL,
            options).toPromise()
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            });
    }
}
```

After login, all my calls to server failed with 403 response code and with message:

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

I checked the response and found following response:

```
[
  {
    "message": "NOT LOGGED"
  }
]
```

What I guessed that it could be CORS issue and the session is not either stored or returned back to server.

I also used chrome CORS plugin but of no help.

The last thing I can think of is to build Angular project and copy the code to node project but this will make my development slow.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not corse issue. Your backend demands some login request with creds first. So after successful login cookie will be saved in client browser. And next requests will have that cookue info attached. If BE doesn't find auth cookie info - it returns error you see

Comment: Yes Alexander, but I can't figure out why cookie is not getting stored or being sent back to BE

Comment: What browser did you use? Can you check cookies is stored in browser? Maybe your BE uses JWT? In that case you should save AccessToken and add it to headers manually.

Comment: No, not using JWT, simply Express session. It works fine with AngularJS, when migrating to Angular5 caused this. No change in BE

Comment: Then provide angularJS code as well fir comparison

Comment: @Ashutosh any update